# Eliminar registro con mismo valor en diferente columna una sola vez

Tags: sql, tsql, trigger

Buenos días, dentro de un **trigger** for insert necesito eliminar todos los registros que tengan un valor mayor a 0 en iva y a la vez eliminar uno que no diga iva del mismo cliente y mismo rut. (No posee primary key)

EJ:

```
Cliente | rut        | precio | ganado | iva    | fecha
────────┼────────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼─────────
Diego   | 23423333-3 | 345344 | 345344 | 0      | 20160111
Diego   | 23423333-3 | 345344 | 345344 | 0      | 20160111
Diego   | 23423333-3 | 345344 | 345344 | 0      | 20160111
Diego   | 23423333-3 | 345344 | 0      | 345344 | 20160111
```

```
delete top (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [dbo] as f 
  inner join inserted as d on (d.rut=f.rut)
  Where f.ganado in(select iva from Inserted) and f.nombre=d.nombre and d.fecha=f.fecha
)
from [dbo] 
from [dbo] as f
inner join inserted as d on (d.rut=f.rut)
Where f.ganado in(select iva from Inserted) and f.nombre=d.nombre and d.fecha=f.fecha
```

DEBERIA: Eliminar la fila con IVA y una con mismo rut, nombre fecha y precio ganado.

EJ:

```
Cliente | rut        | precio | ganado | iva | fecha
────────┼────────────┼────────┼────────┼─────┼─────────
Diego   | 23423333-3 | 345344 | 345344 | 0   | 20160111
Diego   | 23423333-3 | 345344 | 345344 | 0   | 20160111
```

Pero solo elimina valor sin iva, dejando los registros ganados sin eliminarlos (de 1 por 1).

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: por qué quieres hacer esto dentro de un trigger?

Comment: Porque llegan datos desde una fuente externa y necesito limpiarlos.

Comment: Como lo harias si no estuviera dentro de un trigger?

Comment: yo ocuparía una tabla intermedia donde cargar los datos inicialmente y luego insertaría en tu tabla final, limpiando los datos

Comment: Me podrías ayudar con un código para hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ruc NVARCHAR(32), @Nombre  NVARCHAR(32), @fecha   NVARCHAR(32), @iva decimal , @ganado decimal  ,@precio decimal

 /*Eliminamos los registros con IVA mayor a 0*/
SELECT @ruc = rut, @Nombre = nombre, @fecha = fecha , @iva = iva, @ganado  = ganado    , @precio = precio
FROM inserted

DELETE FROM  dbo
WHERE nombre = @Nombre AND
      rut    = @ruc   AND
      iva    > 0


/*Para el paso dos depende. En sql server. La información ya esta insertada. 
  Por lo que al eliminar, eliminarias tambien el registro insertado. Debes distinguir los
  registros con una clave unica. Asi podrias aplicar esto*/

  DELETE FROM  dbo
WHERE nombre = @Nombre AND
      rut    = @ruc    AND
      ganado = @ganado AND
      precio = @precio AND
      fecha  = @fecha  AND
      id     < 15       /*Id insertado, eliminamos los registros que sean iguales y conservamos el ultimo insertado*/
```